# Qual a diferença entre a pseudo classe :root e o * {} no CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, pseudo-classes

Os dois têm a mesma função? Ambos definem de modo generalista determinados procedimentos. Quando eu devo usar um ou outro?

Comment: CSS não é meu forte mas acho que :root { ... } é mais equivalente a html { ... }, ou seja, ao elemento de topo, que é um único elemento, apesar de conter todos os outros. * { ... } define atributos para todos os tipos de elementos (p, h1, h2, h3, div, span, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não, eles não têm a mesma função.

Da [wiki W3C](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:root):

> A pseudo-classe `:root` representa um elemento que está na raiz do document. No HTML, será sempre o elemento HTML.

De forma análoga, se você estiver em um documento SVG, o [`:root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:root) será o elemento SVG. Em suma, você pode utilizar o `:root` para selecionar o elemento de mais alto nível de qualquer documento.

O seletor [`*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors), também chamado de seletor universal, irá selecionar qualquer elemento do documento.

Veja a diferença:

```css
:root {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
}

* {
  border: solid 1px #FF9800;
  background-color: rgba(255, 152, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Olá</span>, <strong>mundo</strong><em>!</em>
</p>
```

Note que o `:root` selecionou apenas o elemento de maior nível do documento. Se você abrir as ferramentas do desenvolvedor, verá que é o elemento `html`. O seletor universal, por outro lado, selecionou todos os elementos da página.

#### Referência:

- [What's the difference between CSS3's `:root` pseudo class and `html`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899615/whats-the-difference-between-css3s-root-pseudo-class-and-html)